# remove duplicate entry in xml in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have duplicate entry in my xml  column in my sql table see material8 key.I remove one entry.I am trying below query its removing both.Is there any way i can remove only one entry.

```
Update mytable set xml = replace (xml, "<Book key=\"material8\"  active=\"true\" displayOrder=\"5\" />", "") where id = 9 and type_key="mykey1";


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Type key="test1" publicKey="test2" >
    <UIProperties>
        <label locale="en_US">My book</label>
    </UIProperties>
    <Books>
        <Book key="material1"  active="true" displayOrder="0" >
            <UIProperties>
                <label locale="en_US">My Books</label>
            </UIProperties>
        </Book>
        <Book key="material2"  />
        <Book key="material3"  active="true" displayOrder="3" >
            <Pages>
                <Page key="material4" active="true" displayOrder="0" />
                <Page key="material5"  active="true" displayOrder="1" />
            </Pages>
        </Book>
        <Book key="material6"  active="true" displayOrder="4" />
        <Book key="material7"  active="true" displayOrder="2" />
        <Book key="material8" active="true" displayOrder="5" />
        <Book key="material8"  active="true" displayOrder="5" />
    </Books>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute key="desc" />
        <Attribute key="date1" />
        <Attribute key="date2" />
    </Attributes>
</Type>
```

Comment: Replace "<book .../>\r\n<book .../>" by "<book .../>"

Comment: Have you seen my solution? Did it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to replace 2 books to 1, instead of 1 to none:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET xml = REPLACE(xml, "<Book key=\"material8\"  active=\"true\" displayOrder=\"5\" /><Book key=\"material8\"  active=\"true\" displayOrder=\"5\" />", "<Book key=\"material8\"  active=\"true\" displayOrder=\"5\" />")
WHERE id = 9
AND type_key="mykey1";
```